# progressbar process freeze for big files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, progress-bar

I have a progress bar

```
<progress class="ProgressBar" id="ProgressBar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

in javascript I did this:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function (e) {
   message.innerHTML=rec.toFixed(0)+"% uploaded..."
   pbar.value = rec.toFixed(0);
}
```

when I upload small files I can see the progress bar changing from 0 to 100% but when I want to upload big files it stops and when the file finish uploading then suddenly it shows 100%
but when I put an alert here then it shows the progress bar process also for big files

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  alert("xxx");
  message.innerHTML=rec.toFixed(0)+"% uploaded..."
  pbar.value = rec.toFixed(0);
}
```

THIS IS MY QUESTION: I don't want to use alert how can I make a delay here so that I can see the progress?

Thanks in advance